# How to compare panda.Series with a dynamic comparator?

Tags: python, pandas, dynamic, comparator, series

I do have a working solution. I'm rather pleased with myself for actually finding one. However, it seems like there should be a better way that I am unaware of at the moment?

I want to be able to dynamically specify which comparator to use when comparing a panda.Series to another panda.Series or a scalar.

My current solution

```py
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

    def func(data, values, shifts, comparator):
        _if   = comparator[0]( data.shift( shifts[0] ), values[0] )
        _then = comparator[1]( data.shift( shifts[1] ), values[1] )
        _else = comparator[2]( data.shift( shifts[2] ), values[2] )

        return data[ np.where(_if, _then, _else) ]

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        series = pd.Series([1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 1, 1, 1])

        filter = series[ np.where(series == 0, series.shift(1) > 0, series > 0) ]

        filter2 = func(
                     data=series, 
                     values=[0,0,0], 
                     shifts=[0,1,0], 
                     comparator=[pd.Series.eq, pd.Series.gt, pd.Series.gt]
                       )
```

Both `filter`and `filter2` give the exact same, expected output. I just can't help but think there is a better way than my custom function, `func()`

To explain the code:

`series` refers to Random Walk data over time. `1` is a step up, `-1` is a step down, `0` is it stays the same. I wrote `func()` to be able to find when the data is stepping up or stepping down. I wanted the ability to choose between, looking for, stepping up or stepping down in as little code as possible.

Comment: the version in `func` looks much less readable to me!  without knowing more about why you want to do this I feel that suggesting anything "better" would be premature optimisation

Comment: version..? So, `series` is data from a random walk over time, `1` is a step up, `-1` is a step down, `0` is it stays the same. I made `func()` as a general function to see when the data is stepping up or when the data is stepping down. I then tried to make it as generalized as possible in case of need in future unrelated projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when I said "version" I was referring to the code that went into getting a useful result and putting it into `filter` or `filter2`, in my mind these are version 1 and 2 respectively.  to expand on my "readability" comment, notice how much code there is in each one:

1. the first version has one line of code, it's pretty obvious what each part of it is doing and why
2. the version using `func` involves 10 lines of code and has a much higher cognitive load. I, the reader of the code, has to thread lots of state into and out of the function

as an example, what if I wanted to get values where two consecutive values where > 0, the naive solution would be:

```
series[(series > 0) & (series.shift(1) > 0)]
```

but using `func`, while I think it should be possible, I certainly can't write it as easily as the above.  the more complicated things I've wanted to do with monte carlo chains certainly couldn't be expressed with it

in general I'd discourage you from trying to write as "generalized as possible" code, especially because "in future" things tend not to happen, or at least happen differently enough that your "general" code isn't general enough.  that said, trying to think/work though exercises like this does serve a useful purpose, and you'll certainly find ways of applying things you discovered/learned.  trying to write the most general thing is almost always a mistake, determining the right level of abstraction is hard and takes a lot of practice and experience

this sort of thing happens enough that there's even a term for it: ["You aren't gonna need it"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).  there are lots of [blog articles](http://josdejong.com/blog/2015/01/06/code-reuse/) saying similar things

hope that's useful, sorry it was a bit rambling!

Comment: If I always do the simple solution then I have to finish my projects sooner!! But for real, that makes a lot of sense. I thought I was being clever, didn't realize YAGNI was a thing. Thanks!